# Session does not save

Tags: asp.net

I'm very new to ASP.NET so there is a high risk that I am missing something simple here, but I have a problem with my Session. When I click the "NewTurn" button the first time, it creates the player just as it should, however, when I click it again, somehow all the stats are back as if it got created again (stats such as "health" is back to max value) but I can see in debug mode that it only enters the "if == null" function ONCE.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, here is the code:

```
protected void NewTurn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        StartButton.Visible = false;
        RulesLink.Visible = false;
        NewTurnButton.Visible = true;

        if (Session["PrevObject"] == null)
        {
            Character player = new Character(1);
            Session["PrevObject"] = player;
        }

        Character prevObj = (Character)Session["PrevObject"];

        prevObj = CreateCard(prevObj);

        Session["PrevObject"] = prevObj;
    }
```

EDIT: I found the error and it had nothing to do with the Session, I just returned the object without setting the correct values before sending it back. Thank you for your suggestions, though and I'm sorry to have wasted your time!

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE: while your efforts to improve other people's posts are appreciated, please keep in mind that code spans (`like this`) aren't meant to be used for highlighting -- they're only meant for code within sentences. For example, `if (a == null)` is alright, but not `ASP.NET`. Thanks!

Comment: hi @OneKitten do you mean the words such as C#,ASP.NET,Session are not to be marked? i have seen many posts they have so i have edited this post. Please let me know if i am doing wrong..:)

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE: yes, that's what I mean. I've also seen a lot of other people also doing that incorrectly, so you're not the only one. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check comment in your code

```
protected void NewTurn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        StartButton.Visible = false;
        RulesLink.Visible = false;
        NewTurnButton.Visible = true;

        if (Session["PrevObject"] == null)
        {
            Character player = new Character(1);
            Session["PrevObject"] = player;
        }

        Character prevObj = (Character)Session["PrevObject"];
       // I think here you made mistake 
        prevObj = CreateCard(prevObj);
         // check here again using DEbug point
         // and make sure prevObj not null 
        Session["PrevObject"] = prevObj;
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't return null there but I think it returns the object with full health even if it lost some.

Comment: Nice catch with sessions :)

Answer (score 0):

You should have to mention the Property of the player will be assign to the Session["PrevObject"].
suppose I have the class such as

```
public class Character 
{
  public playtime{get;set;}
  Character(int i)
    {
      playtime=i;
    }
}
```

Now I will code as you mention:

```
    protected void NewTurn_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            StartButton.Visible = false;
            RulesLink.Visible = false;
            NewTurnButton.Visible = true;

            if (Session["PrevObject"] == null)
            {
                Character player = new Character(1);

//Here is a little change you will have to specify what shuold be assign to the  Session //variable
                Session["PrevObject"] = player.playtime;
            }
```

Hope this will help you.
Vote if you find helpful
Thanks is always appreciated.